# System.CalloutException: Script-thrown exception from HTTP class

Tags: integration, calloutexception, netsuite

I am need some help.

I create one integration to ERP and before yesterday the integration working fine.

But yesterday it's fail and the stack trace give me this information:

[image: stack trace from error]

I think it's because the body response is coming null.

In the line that's occor -> response = http.send(request);

The error occors in  that code:

```
 public static Map<SObjectType, List<SObject>> createSalesOrderIntegrate( Order lOrder ){
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        
        String endPoint = REST_SERVICES+'/record/v1/salesorder/eid:'+lOrder.Id+'_SO?replace=item';

        request.setEndpoint(endPoint);
        request.setHeader('Content-Language', 'pt');
        request.setMethod('PUT');
        request.setHeader('Accept', '*/*');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.setTimeout(60000);
        
        NetsuiteSalesOrder salesOrder;
        Map<SObjectType , List<SObject>> mapToUpsert = new Map<SObjectType, List<SObject>>();
        lOrder = getRelatedFieldsValues(lOrder);

        try{
            salesOrder = getSalesOrderFieldsFromOrder(lOrder);
        }catch(Exception e){
            mapToUpsert.put(Log__c.getSObjectType() , new List<SObject>{logger.atError().relatedTo(lOrder.Id)
                                                                        .withRequest(request)
                                                                        .setStatus('Falha')
                                                                        .fromService('createSalesOrder')
                                                                        .setName(LOGNAME)
                                                                        .setCause(e)
                                                                        .log('getSalesOrderFieldsFromOrder')});

            return mapToUpsert;
        }

        Map< String, String > mapExclusiveName = salesOrder.getExclusiveName;
        salesOrder.getExclusiveName = new Map<String,String>();
        
        String body = JSON.serialize(salesOrder, true);
        body = body.remove('\\');
        body = replaceExclusiveName(body, mapExclusiveName);

        request.setBody(body);

        request = OAuth.signRequest(request, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, TOKEN_ID, TOKEN_SECRET);
        HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
        try{
            response = http.send(request);
        }catch(Exception e){
            mapToUpsert.put(Log__c.getSObjectType() , new List<SObject>{logger.atError().relatedTo(lOrder.Id)
                                                                                .withRequest(request)
                                                                                .setStatus('Falha')
                                                                                .fromService('createSalesOrder')
                                                                                .setName(LOGNAME)
                                                                                .setCause(e)
                                                                                .log('getSalesOrderFieldsFromOrder')});

            return mapToUpsert;
        }

        if ( response.getStatusCode() == 204 ) {

            String id;
            String loc = response.getHeader('Location');
            List<String> split = loc.split('/');
            id = split[split.size() - 1];

            lOrder.ExternalIdNetSuite__c = id;
            lOrder.Status = 'Novo';
            lOrder.Id = lOrder.Id;
            mapToUpsert.put(Order.getSObjectType() , new List<SObject>{lOrder});

            mapToUpsert.put(Log__c.getSObjectType(), new List<SObject>{ logger.atInfo().relatedTo(lOrder.Id)
                                                                        .withRequest(request)
                                                                        .withResponse(response)
                                                                        .setStatus('Sucesso')
                                                                        .fromService('createSalesOrder')
                                                                        .setName(LOGNAME)
                                                                        .log()});
        }else{
            mapToUpsert.put(Log__c.getSObjectType(), new List<SObject>{logger.atError().relatedTo(lOrder.Id)
                                                                        .withRequest(request)
                                                                        .withResponse(response)
                                                                        .setStatus('Falha')
                                                                        .fromService('createSalesOrder')
                                                                        .setName(LOGNAME)
                                                                        .log('Sales Order Cretion Error')});
        }
        return  mapToUpsert;
    }
```

Update:

I found some diffrent, the response is comming compreessed Content-Encoding: gzip, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: which line number in your function code is line 764?

Comment: response = http.send(request);

Comment: @EliveltonWalter Can you try to make this callout using Postman and see if it throws the same error?

Comment: I try it, but in the postman works fine

Comment: Is it possible to share a narrowed down code that I can try on my Dev org to see if it is a bug?

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Upon checking internally, there is an ongoing case wherein the customer reported custom Integration with NetSuite started throwing - 'System.CalloutException: Script-thrown exception' from 21-Aug. I will update this thread as I have more information. -Salesforce Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that this issue you reported via salesforce case has been identified as a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=script-thrown-exception-in-apex-callouts&Id=a1p4V000001JitQ) according to which, the workaround would be that

> When the response body is empty remove Content Encoding header from response headers.

You would need to work with the third-party server team (Netsuite) to get the response and headers corrected.

PS: Posting this information here so other facing the same issue might find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Netsuite, they have fixed the issue and Content-Negotiation should now be working.
To solve the issue above (if using Netsuite) please add the following header Accept-Encoding and set it to identity.
Example for OP:

```
request.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', 'identity');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=script-thrown-exception-in-apex-callouts&Id=a1p4V000001JitQ) for this however it is missing some details.

- The error also happens if the response body is not empty
- There is a workaround you can do in Salesforce. Just add this as a header: `req.setHeader('Accept-Encoding', '');`